# Change search engine in mobile safari on iphone to a different provider?

Tags: iphone, search, mobile, safari

Is there anyway when a user lands on our webpage to give them the option to change their default search engine in mobile safari to our search engine?

i was on my iphone and went to yahoo and it asked me if i wanted to change my default to yahoo.

is there anyway to program it to have it change to something else for example my search engine that uses the google framework or duck duck go for example? or are only the big 3 providers allowed (bing, google and yahoo)

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960788/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-change-the-default-search-engine-for-the-iphon. And it seems like the answer is no.

Comment: It appears to be possible. See my answer on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960788/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-change-the-default-search-engine-for-the-ipho jonathanstark

Answer (score 0):

Safari only supports the three options shown in in the Settings app.

Comment: no possible way to hack it someway. i know in firefox your able to hack your own search engine and have users create it as a default option enabling it in the top right of the browser.

Comment: iOS Safari gives you a lot fewer options than Firefox does.